# How to display the View according to the logged user?

Tags: users, entities, views

I'm Creating a view of a specific content type called "requests (Demande)" , Each request is assigned to a specific user (I have two users : "Salaktarus" and "Zaferro") , what I want to know is how to configure the filter so each user ("Salaktarus" or "Zaferro") sees only the requests which he/she is assigned to.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a relationships based on user who is assigned in the request (if he/she is assigned using a reference field , select that field) , then create a filter based on user (the user who is currently logged in and is viewing the table) , use relation to relate user to nodes which he/she is assigned to.

Comment: the type of the field : COMPTABLI  is Entity reference, i have added in relationship : entity reference : field COMPTABLI , and in Contextuel filter : User : Uid , but the problem it show to me only fields who Author currently has created !!! some one can help me?

Comment: How do you assign a user to a request?

Comment: the administrator it is he who affect requests to users, in the form I add a Select type Reference Entity List, and in that Select List there usernames, Admin selected the desired user, and when the user connect it only sees the demand that has affected him Admin

Comment: maybe this tutorial would help : [Using Entity Reference in Views](http://nodeone.se/en/using-entity-reference-in-views)

Comment: of course I also recommend you to use a content type containing a field user reference , that makes every thing easier.